# wordpress order posts by meta_value date in DESC order

Tags: wordpress, sql-order-by, meta-query

I am trying to sort a query to display posts in order of a meta_key value. The value is stored like so: `2018-Mar-23`.

I would like to display posts with a date that is after today, with the closest date for example `2018-Aug-30` being shown first, and the furthest date away `2020-Aug-30` to show last.

I have put a query together, which still mixes all dates up. Here is what i have:

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_type' => 'games' ,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'releasedate',
            'value' => date("Y-M-d"),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        )
    )
);
```

For some reason i can only get this query to work using the compare method `"BETWEEN"`. Using `">"` which i would expect to use, returns no results.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try `'orderby' => 'meta_value',` and `compare' => '>',`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_type' => 'games' ,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_parent' => 0,
    'meta_key' => 'releasedate', 
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'releasedate',
            'value' => date("Y-M-d"),
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '>',
        )
    )
);
```